# Phone application for classical games

Tags: websites

I am looking for mobile phone website where I can download and replay games of Tal, Smyslov, Alekhine, Lasker etc.

Could anyone with help me with info?

Answer (score 2):

You can download a PGN viewer for your phone platform, then search chessgames.com for your favorite players and their games for playback.  Having a PGN viewer installed is helpful also for sites like chessbase or chessvibes that sometimes link straight to the games file and not an online viewer.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to [free chessgames database](http://www.chessgames.com/index.html) and search and replay any game that you like.